# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: android

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void com.andremion.counterfab.CounterFab.setCount(int)' on a
>   null object reference

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

   fab.setCount(new Database(getBaseContext()). getCountCart());

    if (adapter!=null )
    {
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your full code here

Comment: on a onResume just check `if(fab != null)`.

Comment: ok done ..after run it shows black screen why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did not initialize the `fab` variable. Thus you receive a `NullPointerException`. As this variable seems to be global, you should at any place initialize the `fab` variable in your code before you call functions on it. Since you use it already in the `onResume()` function, you'd best initialize it in your `onCreate()`

Comment: already initialized in onCreate() method